# can't target the element <i> with input:checked

Tags: css, forms, radio-button, background-image

I've a form that's roughly like this -

```
<form action="#">
  <ul class="task-type-options">
    <li class="task-type-item">
      <label for="name-type"><input type="radio" name="task-type">
        <i class="radio-button"></i>
        Thing1 -
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="task-type-item">
      <label for="name-type"><input type="radio" name="task-type">
        <i class="radio-button"></i>
        Thing2 -
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

What I want is for the input[type="radio"] to be replaced by the `<i>` and when checked, change the background-position of the `<i>` element. Here's my CSS

```
    .task-type-item {
      width: 100%;
      list-style: none;
    }
    .task-type-item input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }
    .task-type-item i {
      background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display: block;
      height: 17px;
      margin: 0 8px 0 0;
      width: 17px;
    }
    .task-type-item:hover i {
      background-position: -17px 0;
    }
    .task-type-item input:checked ~ i {
      background-position: -34px 0;
    }

    i {
      display: block;
    }

    label {
      display: block;
    }
```

I know this line

```
.task-type-item input:checked ~ i {
  background-position: -34px 0;
}
```

isn't correct but what I want to do is change the `<i>` when the input is 'checked' and can't work out where I'm going wrong. I've tried > and + and can't get them working either.

I don't really want to rely on jQuery/JavaScript for this, except for OldIE.

Comment: Does the selector apply when you remove the `~ i`? For example: `.task-type-item input:checked { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Hi Andy, no it doesn't. This could mean I've structured the HTML incorrectly for the technique to work, hmm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's one problem here: because your checkboxes are `display:none` you're actually not able to click and check them. You're hovering and clicking on the `i` item, that's why your CSS is not working. You might have to rely on javascript for this.

EDIT:
Forget the above. Couple of things are wrong in your code: 
The for attribute of the  tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together. Or don't use `id` at all, since the target `radio` is enclosed on it's own `label`:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Second: the selector should be `.task-type-item input:checked ~ i`

check working solution here: http://codepen.io/lucianodinapoli/pen/vwqKH

Comment: According to http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/ :checked should work on hidden form elements.